# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.example

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

I am trying to parse json using retrofit.I am trying to display the values in listview using `BaseAdapter`. When I am using map inside `BaseAdapter` I am getting the following error.

**java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.example.prakash.pix91.get.Templates.pixjson.EffectList at com.example.prakash.pix91.get.Templates.multiple_array.MyContactAdapter2.getView(MyContactAdapter2.java:76)**

What am i doing wrong here?

Thankyou

**MyContactAdapter2.java**

```
    public class MyContactAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Map<String, List<EffectList>>> contactList;
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyContactAdapter2(Context context, List<Map<String, List<EffectList>>> objects) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        contactList = objects;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Integer s = contactList.size();
        Log.d("Total count ", s.toString());
        return contactList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return contactList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder1 vh1;
        if (convertView == null) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.get_layout_row_view, parent, false);
            vh1 = ViewHolder1.create((RelativeLayout) view);
            view.setTag(vh1);
        } else {
            vh1 = (ViewHolder1) convertView.getTag();
        }


        EffectList item = (EffectList) getItem(position);


        //   vh.textViewName.setText(item.getEffectsId());


        vh1.textViewName.setText(item.getEffectsName());
        vh1.textViewEmail.setText(item.getEffectsId());

        // Picasso.with(context).load(item.getProfilePic()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(vh.imageView);

        return vh1.rootView;
    }


    private static class ViewHolder1 {
        public final RelativeLayout rootView;
        public final ImageView imageView;
        public final TextView textViewName;
        public final TextView textViewEmail;

        private ViewHolder1(RelativeLayout rootView, ImageView imageView, TextView textViewName, TextView textViewEmail) {
            this.rootView = rootView;
            this.imageView = imageView;
            this.textViewName = textViewName;
            this.textViewEmail = textViewEmail;
        }

        public static MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder1 create(RelativeLayout rootView) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView textViewName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            TextView textViewEmail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
            return new MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder1(rootView, imageView, textViewName, textViewEmail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your `JSON` has not been parsed "as you want".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at this line:

```
 EffectList item = (EffectList) getItem(position);
```

Your items are not `EffectList`s, they're a list of `Map` as you can see here:

```
List<Map<String, List<EffectList>>> contactList;
```

You've overridden the `getItem` method and it returns the appropriate map from the List. Since you're getting a `Map` returned by the `getItem` call, you need to rethink the logic for getting the `EffectList` out of it.

I don't know what you're trying to do with this complex structure of `List<Map<String, List<EffectList>>>`, but maybe you wanted to just have a `List<EffectList`?